# codenameone Font True Type navtive:Mainthin chinese garbled

Tags: themes, codenameone, truetype, chinese-locale

codenameone Font True Type navtive:Mainthin  chinese garbled. when I use navtive:Mainthin and use chinese the result will be unintelligible text.

Comment: Is this on the simulator or on device? Which simulator skin/host OS or device is used.